# Unable to get IPV4 with dhcpcd on Alpine in a dual stack setup

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, alpine-linux, ipv4, dhcpcd

After installing `dhcpcd`, the machine is unable to get IPv4 from DHCP, but generate IPv6 as expected and get DHCPv6 options (like DNS, domain, etc.); the config in `/etc/networking/interfaces` is

```bash
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` I have:

```bash
hostname
duid
persistent
vendorclassid
option interface_mtu
option host_name
option ntp_servers
option rapid_commit
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
```

The version fo Alpine is `3.18` and the version of `dhcpcd` is `10.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the DHCP server doesn't support the use of DUID as ClientID so the solution is to disable the option `duid`